# Overlaying geom_line on boxplot fails when there is only one observation per grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I’m having some trouble getting the graph I’d like.  I have some data where multiple values exist for one group, but the other group only has one data (i.e. All States v. Only DC).

I’d like to generate a box plot for the “all states” data and then overlay a line plot.  My attempts and comments are show below (it should be a complete example that runs alone).  How do I get the line version of the plot below to work?

```
# --- RCODE ----------------------------------

library(ggplot2)

hiv_rate_data <- data.frame(
  state=c("ME","VT","CT","NY","ME","VT","CT","NY","ME","VT","CT","NY"),
  year=c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022,2022,2022),
  rate_per_100000=c(1,2,3,20,1,20,3,4,20,2,3,4)
)

hiv_rate_data

hiv_rate_data_dc <- data.frame(
  state=c("DC","DC","DC"),
  year=c(2020,2021,2022),
  rate_per_100000=c(20,10,7)
)

hiv_rate_data_dc

# the following works (create geom_line required group=1)
ggplot(hiv_rate_data,aes(x=year,y=rate_per_100000,group=1))+
  geom_line(
  data=hiv_rate_data_dc,
  aes(y=rate_per_100000, color=factor(state)))


# this works (requires group=year)
ggplot(hiv_rate_data,aes(x=year,y=rate_per_100000, group=year))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA)+
  geom_point(
    data=hiv_rate_data[!is.na(hiv_rate_data$outlier),], 
    aes(x=factor(year), y=rate_per_100000, color=factor(state))
  )+
  geom_point(
    data=hiv_rate_data_dc, 
    aes(group=factor(year), y=rate_per_100000, color=factor(state)))+
  scale_colour_discrete("State")+
  labs(x="Year", y="Rate per 100000")

# this does not render the line and gives the error:
# "`geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation"
ggplot(hiv_rate_data,aes(x=year,y=rate_per_100000, group=year))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA)+
  geom_point(
    data=hiv_rate_data[!is.na(hiv_rate_data$outlier),], 
    aes(x=factor(year), y=rate_per_100000, color=factor(state))
  )+
  geom_line(
    data=hiv_rate_data_dc, 
    aes(group=factor(year), y=rate_per_100000, color=factor(state)))+
  scale_colour_discrete("State")+
  labs(x="Year", y="Rate per 100000")

# this does not render the line and gives the error:
# "`geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation"
ggplot(hiv_rate_data,aes(x=year,y=rate_per_100000, group=1))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA)+
  geom_point(
    data=hiv_rate_data[!is.na(hiv_rate_data$outlier),], 
    aes(x=factor(year), y=rate_per_100000, color=factor(state))
  )+
  geom_line(
    data=hiv_rate_data_dc, 
    aes(group=factor(year), y=rate_per_100000, color=factor(state)))+
  scale_colour_discrete("State")+
  labs(x="Year", y="Rate per 100000")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the expected outcome?

```r
library(ggplot2)

hiv_rate_data <- data.frame(
  state=c("ME","VT","CT","NY","ME","VT","CT","NY","ME","VT","CT","NY"),
  year=c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022,2022,2022),
  rate_per_100000=c(1,2,3,20,1,20,3,4,20,2,3,4)
)

hiv_rate_data_dc <- data.frame(
  state=c("DC","DC","DC"),
  year=c(2020,2021,2022),
  rate_per_100000=c(20,10,7)
)

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(
    data = hiv_rate_data, 
               aes(x = factor(year), y = rate_per_100000,
                   group = year),
               outlier.color = NA
    ) +
  geom_point(
    data = hiv_rate_data[!is.na(hiv_rate_data$outlier),], 
    aes(x = factor(year), y = rate_per_100000,
        color = factor(state), group = year)
    ) +
  geom_line(
    data = hiv_rate_data_dc, 
    aes(x = factor(year), y = rate_per_100000,
        color = factor(state),
        group = 1)
    )+
  scale_colour_discrete("State")+
  labs(x="Year", y="Rate per 100000")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>